# Provider Hosted App-Not able to get data from list using JSOM or Javascript in sharepoint 2016 On-Premise

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, jsom, sharepoint-on-prem, provider-hosted-app

My Provider-Hosted App published and hosted on IIS with `https`. The URL is like:

```
https://localhost:44343/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fecontent&0319c41%2Eecontent%2Eelibrary%2Eapps%2Elocal%2FSharePointApp2%5Fsingeltest
```

How can I get list data using JavaScript or JSOM.

Please share the helpful code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a cross domain call.

Refer:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/access-sharepoint-data-from-add-ins-using-the-cross-domain-library